# Bipartite Graphs in R's igraph Package

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to create a bipartite graph w/ R's igraph package, but having a devil of a time.

Can anyone tell me why this works:

```
g <- graph.bipartite( rep(0:1,length=10), c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
```

But this gives me an error:

```
g <- graph.bipartite( rep(0:1,length=10), c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19))
Error in graph.bipartite(rep(0:1, length = 10), c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14,  : 
  At bipartite.c:438 : Invalid (negative) vertex id, Invalid vertex id
```

Comment: thanks to both Henry and Tamas! I see now where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `graph.bipartite` implicitly specifies the number of vertices. In both cases, you will have 10 vertices in your graph. However, since vertices have consecutive numeric IDs starting from zero in igraph, you cannot use 10, 11 etc as vertex IDs.

Answer (score 1):

With your `graph.bipartite( rep(0:1, length=10), ...)` you have told `graph.bipartite` that there are ten vertices in the graph, and it treats them as 0,1,2,...9.

You could have written

`graph.bipartite( c(0,0,1,0), c(0,2,1,2,2,3))`

with four vertices 0, 1, 2, and 3 (with 2 in one part and 0, 1 and 3 in the other) but not

`graph.bipartite( c(0,0,1,0), c(0,2,1,2,2,4))`

because there is no vertex 4, nor

`graph.bipartite( c(0,0,1,0), c(0,2,1,2,1,3))`

because the attempted edge (1,3) joins two vertices in the same part.